# Load images with substring in filename from a given path

Tags: python, image

i try to load image by part of name, for example image_dir  is a variable folder,
in some different folder i have single image with name "Cat smile.png" or "cat go crazy.jpeg" (note uppercase lowercase Cat , cat) i find glob.glob() but not sure if is right way

```
image_dir = ###string variable
my_image = "Cat" or "cat"or "caT" or "CAT"

###want to find photo with that part of name if exist

image = os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"),image_dir + os.sep + my_image)
```

edit: i think is not good way because i think best way to make that is use append image from directory with :

```
image_dir = ###string variable
directory = os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"),image_dir)
images = []
for fn in os.listdir(directory):
    images.append(fn)
```

now i can find image name from images because is a list... but I'm not able

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regular expression example.**

For the most part this is a generic python question, some answers from stack overflow.

[python finding substring inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196176/python-finding-substring-inside-string)

[Python glob multiple extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959878/python-glob-multiple-extensions)

[Python glob multiple filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes)

For blender specifics, the image file extensions that your blender can open are

```
>>> bpy.path.extensions_image
frozenset({'.dpx', '.pdd', '.jp2', '.hdr', '.j2c', '.rgb', '.tiff', '.sgi', '.tga', '.rgba', '.png', '.cin', '.jpg', '.exr', '.tif', '.dds', '.psd', '.psb', '.bmp', '.jpeg', '.tx'})
```

Here is a sample method, that searches for image files that have a substring in their name and an extension suitable to blender. A regular expression search is used in both cases. The searches are case insensitive.

The links above show how to do this using other tools such as `glob, pathlib` and `fnmatch`

```
import bpy

def find_files(substring, path='.', extensions=[]):
    from os import listdir
    from re import search, IGNORECASE
    return [f for f in listdir(path) 
            if search(r'%s' % substring, f, IGNORECASE) 
            and any(search(r'%s$' % ext, f, IGNORECASE) 
                    for ext in extensions)]

def image_files(substring, path="."):
    return find_files(substring, path=path, extensions=bpy.path.extensions_image)

def movie_files(substring, path="."):
    return find_files(substring, path=path, extensions=bpy.path.extensions_movie)

def audio_files(substring, path="."):
    return find_files(substring, path=path, extensions=bpy.path.extensions_audio)

# test call, search for "screenshot" in image folder 
# and load images 
from os.path import join
image_path = "/home/batfinger/Pictures"
for fp in image_files("screenshot", path=image_path):
    print(fp)
    bpy.data.images.load(join(image_path, fp))
```

Notes maybe switch extension search to first. For recursive folder search would use something like `os.walk` instead of `os.listdir`

Comment: I didn't know about `bpy.path.extensions_image`, great find Mr. Holmes! I don't think that such useful attrib deserve any documentation: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=extensions_image&check_keywords=yes&area=default BTW: awesome post on meta...